# LDAP bind Authentication Handler

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, cas

I want to establish a conection from my central authentication service (CAS)  to verify the identity of my users on active directory.
But I find myself with the following error:

```
[LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, how: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., Data 0, v1db1]; Remaining name 'cn = Users, dc = aimed, dc = local'
```

If anyone knows about this problem, please help me.
Here is my code :

```
<!-- LDAP bind Authentication Handler +-->
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler">
<property name="filter" value="uid=%u" />
<property name="searchBase" value="cn=Users,dc=aimed,dc=local" />
<property name="contextSource" ref="LDAPcontextSource" />
<property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="yes" /> <!-- fix because of how AD returns results +-->
</bean>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="LDAPcontextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
<property name="pooled" value="false"/>
<property name="urls">
<list>
<value>ldap://server.aimed.local/ </value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="userDn" value="uid=AIMED\aimed, dc=aimed, dc=local"/>
<property name="password" value="system_123"/>
<property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
<map>
<entry>
<key>
<value>java.naming.security.authentication</value>
</key>
<value>simple</value>
</entry>
</map>
</property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

`BindLdapAuthenticationHandler` implements a two-phase (lookup & bind) authentication, but Active Directory doesn't allow anonymous access per default.  You'll have to bind using a service account, first.  Alternatively, if your users are all immediate children of the baseDN, you could switch to `FastBindLdapAuthenticationHandler`.